# Admin 403 error: cpTrigger no longer working properly

Tags: admin

Typing "/admin" on local or remote server yields a server generated 403 forbidden error. Fortunately I can still login to the Craft 4 admin if I type "/admin/login".

What I've checked/tested:

- cpTrigger: config/general.php shows 'cpTrigger' => App::env('CP_TRIGGER') ?: 'admin',
- cleared cookies
- disabled non-essential plugins

Comment: Have you checked the user permissions for the user you're trying to login as? It's possible something is unchecked in the list that shouldn't be.

Comment: Thanks @cherrykoda - This is a Solo version so there's no user permission settings - just admin.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Next step - if you set that general.config setting to 'cpTrigger' => 'admin' does it behave the same way? This will narrow down if its an env problem or a system one.

Comment: Yes @cherrykoda , when I simplify the config file setting using your suggestion above, the behavior is the same.